# Any way to make break point symbols be on top in the vertical ruler in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, settings, customization

The problem is that search results overlap and make it hard to see whether I've set a break point or not. Any ideas how to remedy this? I can't seem to find a customizable order of which symbols are displayed on the vertical ruler.

[alt text http://www.imagepaste.com/img/02f37e8804b2ba32af5b13a692f47cb0.png](http://www.imagepaste.com/img/02f37e8804b2ba32af5b13a692f47cb0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround: set the Annotation for Breakpoints to include a "vertical bar". This will place a thin vertical line to the left of the line with the breakpoint. Good enough I guess.